# Android Visualizer without RECORD_AUDIO uses permission

Tags: android

I'm using a simple Visualizer class (see below) to visualize audio output from the `MediaPlayer` class. However, this requires `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` which seems to scare off users. Is there any way to achieve the same result, but not ues the `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`?

Visualizer code:

```
private void setupVisualizerFx() {
    int audioSessionId = service.getAudioSessionId();
    if (mVisualizer != null) {
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
    }
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(audioSessionId);
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
    try {
        mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(
            new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
                public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
                        byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                    mVisualizerView.updateVisualizer(bytes);
                }

                public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
                        byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                }
            }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);
}

/**
 * A simple class that draws waveform data received from a
 * {@link Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener#onWaveFormDataCapture }
 */
class VisualizerView extends View {
    private byte[] mBytes;
    private float[] mPoints;
    private Rect mRect = new Rect();

    private Paint mForePaint = new Paint();

    public VisualizerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();

    }

    private void init() {
        mBytes = null;

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        String txtColorString = sharedPref.getString(
                PreferencesActivity.KEY_PREF_TXT_COLOR, "");
        int txtColor = Integer.parseInt(txtColorString);

        mForePaint.setStrokeWidth(1f);
        mForePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mForePaint.setColor(txtColor);
    }

    public void updateVisualizer(byte[] bytes) {
        mBytes = bytes;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mBytes == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mPoints == null || mPoints.length < mBytes.length * 4) {
            mPoints = new float[mBytes.length * 4];
        }

        mRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        for (int i = 0; i < mBytes.length - 1; i++) {
            mPoints[i * 4] = mRect.width() * i / (mBytes.length - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 1] = mRect.height() / 2
                    + ((byte) (mBytes[i] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2)
                    / 128;
            mPoints[i * 4 + 2] = mRect.width() * (i + 1)
                    / (mBytes.length - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 3] = mRect.height() / 2
                    + ((byte) (mBytes[i + 1] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2)
                    / 128;
        }

        canvas.drawLines(mPoints, mForePaint);
    }
}
```

Any alternative suggestions to the Visualizer class?

Comment: Not really, unless you plan on implementing a `MediaPlayer` yourself (i.e. do all the file parsing, decoding, etc) so that you have access to the decoded PCM data.